# How can I set the label width relative to the parent node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create a kind of a multinode in tikz with little comments in the corners of the node.
In my example I solved it via a label and the comment it is in the right lower corner.(1)
I want to avoid that my comment is running in other areas of the node and I set the text width.

But I have problems to set the width to the half of the main box.

How can I set the text width of the label relative to the size of the main box?

(1) I could also do it by defining a new macro, like in http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/periodic-table-of-chemical-elements/
But I prefer to do it with labels.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}%if used with lualatex
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
      box/.style={
          text width=5cm,align=center,minimum height=4cm,rectangle,draw,rounded corners,
      },
      commentedbox/.style={
          %The label should be 1/2 of the width of the actual node
          label={[anchor=south east,
          %text width=0.5\tikzlastnode.x,% half width of current main node,  How???
          font=\footnotesize,]south east:{#1}}
      }
    ]
  %label as argument of node  with manual text width
  \node[box,
      label={[anchor=south east,font=\footnotesize,text width=25mm]south east:{Here is a comment for box 1. It should use half of the main box size}}
    ] (box1) {The main text of box 1};
  %label as argument of style
  \node[below =of box1.south,
      box,commentedbox={Here is a comment for box 2.  It should use half of the main box size}
    ] {The main text of box 2};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In box 2 I want the same look as in box 1, but without a fix text width. The text in the corner should be the half width of the box.

Comment: If you don't set the `text width` (or use a `\parbox`), you can't wrap the text.  You can compute the width of a named node, but it is more effort than it is worth.  Easiest is to set the width of the parent using a macro or length which can be accessed by the label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to use an `extra` node with `text width` based in `\tikzlastnode` (main node) width:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}%if used with lualatex
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
      box/.style={
          text width=5cm,
          align=center,
          minimum height=4cm,
          rectangle,
          draw,
          rounded corners,
      },
      commentedbox/.style={
            append after command={
                \pgfextra
                \path let 
                \p1=($(\tikzlastnode.south)-(\tikzlastnode.south east)$), 
                \n2={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
                node[draw, rounded corners,
                    %inner xsep=0pt,
                    text width=\n2-.666em,
                    anchor=south east, font=\footnotesize] 
                    at (\tikzlastnode.south east) {#1};
                \endpgfextra}}
    ]
  %label as argument of node  with manual text width
  \node[box,
  label={[anchor=south east, font=\footnotesize,
  text width=25mm] south east:{Here is a comment for box 1. It should use half of the main box size}}
    ] (box1) {The main text of box 1};
  %label as argument of style
  \node[below =of box1.south,
      box, commentedbox={Here is a comment for box 2.  It should use half of the main box size}
    ] (box2) {The main text of box 2};
    \draw (box2.south)--(box2.north);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]